# neural network performs badly at simple linear interpolation task

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, interpolation

FYI: I uploaded all you need to test it yourself (data + a simplified script).

This is my problem:
I tried to train a very simple model that uses four input values
x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3)
to predict value x(4), i.e. y = x(4).

However, I modified the data such that y = x(4) is a perfect linear extrapolation:
y = x(3) + (x(3)-x(2))

The model I used is a single dense layer with four neurons. The weights "0 0 -1 2" would be a perfect solution (loss of "0").

However, I can't make it reach these values.

Can you help or tell me, why?

files are here: https://ufile.io/5d2t4

### main script (with artificial data):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adadelta, Adam
import keras.backend as K

def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt( K.mean( K.square( y_pred - y_true ) ) )

X_train = np.random.random(240000*4)
X_train = np.reshape( X_train, ( 240000, 1, 4 ) )

# predict the gradient of the 
y_train = X_train[:,0,3] - X_train[:,0,2]


inputShape = ( X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2] )


# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add( Flatten( input_shape=inputShape  ) )
model.add( Dense( 1 ) )


model.compile( loss=root_mean_squared_error, optimizer=Adam( decay = 0.1 ) )

# train model
batchSize = 8

model.fit( X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=batchSize, shuffle=True )

y_train_predicted = model.predict( X_train)
y_train_predicted = np.asarray(y_train_predicted).ravel()

y_train_predicted_rmse = np.sqrt( np.mean( np.square( y_train_predicted - y_train ) ) )

print( "y_train RMSE = " + str( y_train_predicted_rmse ) )
```

Comment: Are your neurons linear ??

Comment: We are not going to download your code & work for you. Please post relevant snippets in the question

Comment: @UmangGupta The topic is interesting and I thus privided data for you to experience it yourself based on actual data. If you see this as "working for me" -- you don't have to do anything. If you want to learn from that problem, feel free to use the data provided.

Comment: @Caramiriel, see the update :)

Comment: @S.H Thanks for updating the code. Please find the working code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things I ask myself when my "obvious" models don't converge is if the hyper-params are appropriate.

I tweaked your code to fix the learning rate. I removed decay and added a learning rate of 0.01 instead of 0.001 which is the default (see https://keras.io/optimizers/). The resulting weights after one epoch are

```
    [ 9.3402149e-04],
    [ 5.8139337e-04],
    [-9.9929601e-01],
    [ 1.0009530e+00]
```

which is approximately what we set in the code.

```
    [0, 0, -1, 1]
```

If you just keep the default learning rate (0.001) without decay it works fine too. 
Find the working code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adadelta, Adam
import keras.backend as K

def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt( K.mean( K.square( y_pred - y_true ) ) )

X_train = np.random.random(240000*4)
X_train = np.reshape( X_train, ( 240000, 1, 4 ) )

y_train = X_train[:,0,3] - X_train[:,0,2]

inputShape = ( X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2] )

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add( Flatten( input_shape=inputShape  ) )
model.add( Dense( 1 ) )

model.compile( loss=root_mean_squared_error, optimizer=Adam( lr=0.01 ) )

# train model
batchSize = 8

model.fit( X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=batchSize, shuffle=True )

y_train_predicted = model.predict( X_train)
y_train_predicted = np.asarray(y_train_predicted).ravel()

y_train_predicted_rmse = np.sqrt( np.mean( np.square( y_train_predicted - y_train ) ) )

print( "y_train RMSE = " + str( y_train_predicted_rmse ) )


x = [model.layers]
x[0][1].get_weights()
```

Comment: thanks for trying it out and for the result regarding the learning rate

Comment: @S.HPlease accept the answer if you think it sufficiently answers your problem.